# How to get my html inner texts displayed when it's only taking the space but not displaying the texts?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to print some inner texts inside my html form using JavaScript, the problem is it's not displaying. `console` is not showing any errors and functions are also running smoothly. Right on the breakpoint.

So I changed my text `fontSize` to `500px` to check whether any changes apply. yes! it's only taking the space but not showing the texts. What could be the error?

```js
function validatingForm() {
  var formOkay = true;
  //declaring variables and getting the values using IDs
  var fname = document.getElementById(firstname);
  console.log("firstname" + fname);
  if (fname = "") {
    formOkay = false;
    document.getElementById("textfirstname").innerText = "First Name can not be blanked !";
  }
  if (formOkay == false) {
    document.getElementById("textform").innerText = "Check the red bordered ones again please !";
  } else {
    return formOkay;
  }
}

function init() {
  var formID = document.getElementById("myForm");
  formID.onsubmit = validatingForm;
}
window.onload = init;
```

```css
#textfirstname {
  color: red;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<div class="headerr">
  <header>
    <a href="https://www.swinburne.edu.au/"><img src="images/logo33.png" alt="beta" /></a>
    <h1>THE BETA COMPANY</h1>
  </header>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="navtool">
  <nav>
    <a href="index.html" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> HOME PAGE </a>
    <a href="about.html" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i> ABOUT US </a>
    <a href="jobs.html" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> FIND YOUR JOB HERE </a>
    <a class="active" href="apply.html" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> APPLY NOW </a>
    <a href="enhancements.html" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> ENHANCEMENT </a>
  </nav>
</div>
<article>
  <section id="form">
    <form id="myForm" method="POST" action="https://mercury.swin.edu.au/it000000/formtest.php">
      <label for="firstname">First Name : <span id="textfirstname"></span> </label><br/><input type="text" id="firstname" name="First name" maxlength="20" pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+$" required="required" /><br/><br/>
    </form>
```

Comment: Please add the accompanying HTML and CSS so we can replicate your issue and provide you with an answer. Without it we can't know what the issue is.

Comment: Maybe the css corresponding to the element may have font colour which is not visible to your eyes. Try selecting that element and getting the `innerText` property to check whether it has actually updated or  not.

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt That could be the case, but we can't know for sure unless the OP shows us the HTML and CSS. However, an even easier way to know if that is the issue is to just drag the mouse over that area and see if any characters highlight.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Exactly!! That could be..which is why I used the word __Maybe__

Comment: Please add a [mcve], so that the problem is actually reproducible for anyone trying to help you.

Comment: @ScottMarcus  i have added the html code and css code too. can you please take a look again?

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt i have added the html code and css code too. can you please take a look again?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, a caveat to this answer: All your validation code above does is check if one field is blank or not. If you just want to validate the form to stop empty fields then you already have this working - added the `required` attribute to your textbox element. The validation code you wrote doesn't add any more useful functionality on top of that. This HTML5 validation can also check for other basic validation errors, without you needing to write any extra code.

---

However, if you want to proceed with what you're doing, then here goes:

There are a number of basic errors in your logic and also your understanding of the basics of JavaScript syntax and manipulating DOM elements:

1) `document.getElementById(firstname);` will not return anything useful because `firstname` is not a defined variable. I think you intended to supply the ID of the element instead: `document.getElementById("firstname");` (i.e. use a string literal instead of a variable name)

2) `fname` will never be equal to `""` because it's an *element*, not a string. `var fname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;` will get you what you want - i.e. the content of the textbox, not the textbox object itself.

3) `if (fname = "")` is wrong. It should be `if (fname == "")`. Remember that `=` assigns a value to the variable on the left side of the expression, whereas `==` compares two values against each other. Clearly in this case you want to do a comparison, not set a value.

4) This section:

```
if (formOkay == false) {
    document.getElementById("textform").innerText = "Check the red bordered ones again please !";
  } else {
    return formOkay;
  }
```

makes no logical sense - in order to stop the form from submitting when there are errors, you need to return `false`. Yet here, in the case of errors you don't return any value, so it assumes everything is OK and continues to submit as normal. What you can do is just return `formOkay` in all circumstances, so you're sure you return the correct value:

```
if (formOkay == false) {
    document.getElementById("textform").innerText = "Check the red bordered ones again please !";
}
return formOkay;
```

5) None of the above will be of any real value unless you remove the `required` attribute from the textbox, because, once the validation code is corrected, the function will never be executed until the `required` attribute has been satisfied, at which point the only thing it actually checks for is already valid, so it never displays any errors.

---

Here's a complete working demo with all of that fixed. I added a submit button so we can actually see it in action.

```js
function validatingForm() {
  var formOkay = true;
  var fname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
  console.log("firstname" + fname);
  
  if (fname == "") {
    formOkay = false;
    document.getElementById("textfirstname").innerText = "First Name can not be blanked !";
  }
  
  if (formOkay == false) {
    document.getElementById("textform").innerText = "Check the red bordered ones again please !";
  }
  return formOkay;
}

function init() {
  var formID = document.getElementById("myForm");
  formID.onsubmit = validatingForm;
}
window.onload = init;
```

```css
#textfirstname {
  color: red;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<div class="headerr">
  <header>
    <a href="https://www.swinburne.edu.au/"><img src="images/logo33.png" alt="beta" /></a>
    <h1>THE BETA COMPANY</h1>
  </header>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="navtool">
  <nav>
    <a href="index.html" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> HOME PAGE </a>
    <a href="about.html" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i> ABOUT US </a>
    <a href="jobs.html" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> FIND YOUR JOB HERE </a>
    <a class="active" href="apply.html" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> APPLY NOW </a>
    <a href="enhancements.html" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> ENHANCEMENT </a>
  </nav>
</div>
<article>
  <section id="form">
    <form id="myForm" method="POST" action="https://mercury.swin.edu.au/it000000/formtest.php">
      <label for="firstname">First Name : <span id="textfirstname"></span> </label><br/><input type="text" id="firstname" name="First name" maxlength="20" pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+$" /><br/><br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
      <div id="textform"></div>
    </form>
```

As I said, all of these are fairly basic errors individually. I suggest you pay closer attention to the details of the code you're writing, and also study the available JavaScript methods and syntax some more until you're comfortable and not making basic errors. Also try to improve your debugging skills so you can work through your code line by line and start to see where each individual part fails.